# How to click a checkbox in Java using PhantomJS and Selenium?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, checkbox, phantomjs

I want select a simple checkbox in Java using PhantomJS with Selenuim.

I did it with Firefox with this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='terms-checkbox']")).click();
```

But when I changed to PhantomJS driver I got an error : invisible element ...

Comment: If it's an intense, JS & AJAX-heavy page, the sad truth is PhantomJS (and other headless browsers) just aren't up for the job.

Comment: So , there is no way to do it , even with the last version of PhantomJS 1.9.7 ? Cause , I have to do all my test with a headless browser and it ll be run on a linux Server.

Comment: FwIW, this might just be an issue with PhantomJS not handling label clicks in the same way as conventional browsers.  If I'm testing JavaScript with PhantomJS then I have to manually create and dispatch the mouse event to get click to work.  This unfortunately doesn't help much for Selenium but it may be useful information anyway!

Comment: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12032

Answer (score 0):

The Core problem in my case is on the xpath locator that i was using, in phantomjs if you want to click on the element which have a child div, you need to click on the specific child div of the element

```
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
  <input id="addressUpdate:firmflg_input" name="addressUpdate:firmflg_input" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="addressUpdate:j_idt159" aria-checked="false" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>
</div>
```

if you use this xpath `//div[@id='addressUpdate:firmflg']` for the above code snipet it will fail to click on the checkbox if you running on phantomjs but it works in other browsers.
 instead if you go for `//div[@id='addressUpdate:firmflg']/div[2]`  this will work in all browsers including phantomjs.